# contact point and point of intersection

Tags: soft-question, definition

I am just unable to understand the definitions of contact point and point of intersection.My doubts can be summed up into the following two questions :

1) Suppose $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=0$ are two functions. Can we say that the two functions intersect at $x=0$.

2) Suppose $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$ are two functions. Can we say that the two functions have a point of contact at $x=0$.

Just a yes or no will do but I don't want guesses.

Comment: Can you write here exactly what your definitions are for "point of intersection" and "contact point"? Contact point isn't terribly standard, as far as I know.

Comment: My first line clearly states "I am just unable to understand the definitions of contact point and point of intersection"

Comment: ok... can you write here exactly what your _textbook's/teacher's_ definitions are for "point of intersection" and "contact point"?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I don't know exactly what your definitions are - can you copy them here? If "contact point" means the same as "point where the functions are tangent," then the answers are yes and no respectively.

Comment: My definitions or my textbook's/teacher's definitions don't matter. I want to know the real definition(The way mathematicians define them).

Comment: As I said, the phrase "contact point" is *not standard*, so there isn't a general definition (that I'm aware of). Normally, we say that two functions intersect at $x$ if $f(x) = g(x)$, so the answer to the first question is 'yes.'

Comment: @user61527 Isn't it also necessary for points of intersection to have different tangents?

Comment: Not usually, no.

Comment: That solves the first question but what about the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I think I have understood the facts, thanks to the numerous comments.

What I now understand is that a contact point can also be called a point of intersection. So in point (1) of my question, the point can be said as a contact point or a point of intersection.

Also, in point (2) of my question, the point is a point of intersection but not a point of contact.

Any further suggestions are always welcome.